# Magento 1.9 - Product image resolution issue

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, gallery-image, format

We are facing an issue while trying to upload product images. The `PNG` format images looks fine like original image color/ resolution but `JPG` format images not looks good like the original image. `JPG` image color/resolution looks changed on product view page. Couldn't figure out what is the issue. Screenshots are attached.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed my `JPG` images issue. I saved my `JPG` images in `RGB mode`.Now images looks fine.